# Is it useful to select specific columns in symfony

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-query

I am bit unsure if it is correct to ask such question here as it may be a more of coding standard than a problem.

I work in a team and had an argument with another member on how to fetch columns in doctrine queries. He said that we should be selecting all columns by their names while fetching a record, while I am in favor of fetching just complete row and just required columns.

I will show examples of our versions of code:

**My version:**

```
public function getRecord($fromDate, $toDate)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('table')
        ->andwhere('table.sendFrom <=:sendFrom')
        ->andwhere('table.sendTo >=:sendTo')
        ->setParameter('sendFrom', $fromDate)
        ->setParameter('sendTo', $toDate)
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

**Their Version:**

```
public function getRecord($fromDate, $toDate)
{
    // Sorry had to hide column names
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('table')
        ->select('table.id,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,'
            . 'table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,'
            . 'table.column_1,table.sendFrom,table.sendTo,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,'
            . 'table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,'
            . 'table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,'
            . 'table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,'
            . 'table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,'
            . 'table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,'
            . 'table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,'
            . 'table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.column_1,table.sendTo,'
            . 'table.sendFrom')
        ->andwhere('table.sendFrom <=:sendFrom')
        ->andwhere('table.sendTo >=:sendTo')
        ->setParameter('sendFrom', $fromDate)
        ->setParameter('sendTo', $toDate)
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

While I find my version more future-proof as if we add a new column in table, we will not have to add new column name in all queries, their argument is that their version is more secure and fast. When I asked them to give a proof, they refused to.

I am looking for your opinions on:

1. Am I right or wrong in my argument.
2. If I am right then what proof/argument I can present to team

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are using the ORM here and ultimately ending up with Doctrine entities?  If, so the second approach is dangerous as you end up with entities only partially hydrated.  Downstream users may assume that certain properties are valid when they are not.  On the other hand, if these are just arrays then no problem though having a table with that many columns strikes me as a potentially poor design regardless.

Comment: Yes.. This was exact point where our argument started. I wanted to get objects of entities through my version but their approach gives me arrays. But again in their argument, "array is faster than objects" as doctrine don't have to hydrate fields in objects anymore. As mater of poor design, "Order" table is an example of a table with large no of fields though.

Comment: It is a bit off topic but I one reason I moved away from the ORM some years ago was simply because one entity per table mapping proved to be overly restrictive.  I follow the second example though in most cases I then convert the arrays to query specific objects just for the sake of downstream sanity.  So I guess I am in the "their" camp especially when multiple tables and various aggregates are involved.  In your example, I suspect there are plenty of times that only a few columns from the order table are actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance "Their version" is the best, only necessary fields will be mapped (but I think the gain is negligible).

In terms of maintenance "My version" is the best, you're right if you need to add a column you have to add it in all repositories...

In terms of security, I think it's a non-argument, the job is not to expose sensitive fields in your response (HTML response, Json response...)

But it's my personal opinions.

Comment: My opinion is also the same. Gains are almost negligible given the cost of hardware available today. We can get a VPS and if it still comes short, add more VPS under a load balancer. I think gains, we get through maintenance ease, can cover up hardware costs.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting datas from a database always comes at a cost. While it may not make a huge difference while testing your application, it is different when thousands of users are querying your database at the same time.

However, code quality and maintainability is also an important factor, and it's not always worth making a huge mess only to gain 0.00000% in performances. So if you need all columns from a row except for one containing something tiny like an int, i'd go with the whole row.

There are things you can do to improve code readability and reusability. I like to construct my repositories as a set of small function that do something specific to the database with a readable name that i can then use in my controller:

```
public function initQuery() 
{
    $this->qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('table');

    return $this;
}

public function selectRows()
{
    $this->qb->addSelect('table.row1, table.row2, table.row3...');

    return $this;
}

public function orderByDate() 
{
    $this->qb->addOrderBy('table.date', 'ASC');

    return $this;
}

public function getResult()
{
    return $this->qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

Then i can use it like this:

```
$rows = $repository
    ->initQuery()
    ->selectRows()
    ->orderByDate()
    ->getResult()
;
```

Comment: Some repos have like 10 methods and all of them need different fields. I think 10 "selectRows" functions will further complicate the solution.

Comment: Then you create a method per set of fields that you need. Let's say i have a database with authors, books, author's address. I create the methods getAuthors(), getBooks(), getAddress(), etc. That way, in my controller i can chain all the methods i need to get the datas. Sometime i just need the author, sometimes i need just the author and it's address. The repository methods dont' change and the controller's code i very human readable. I'm pretty sure that in your repos methods, you have redundancies in your queries. Regroup those redundant fields in methods and chain them.